# How do I POST variables using jQuery / Javascript to another page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

How do I use POST using jQuery/Javascript to send to another page and redirect to that page?

Sending variables using GET...

In Javascript

```
window.location = 'receivepage.php?variable='+testVariable;
```

When it is receive by PHP...

```
$var = $_GET['variable'];
```

How do I do that ^ , using $_POST?

I already tried...

```
$.post(
'receivepage.php', {
 i: i
 }, function(){
 window.location = 'receivepage.php';
 }
);
```

but it seems to lose the variable when it reaches PHP

Comment: Your "$.post()" calls the variable "i"; is the php code still looking for "variable"?

Answer (score 2):

Doing $.post is trying to post the information via ajax, and THEN redirecting to your page, so when you finally get there, the attribute "i" won't be received.

You could do someothing like this:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" target="receivepage.php" id="myform">
   <input type="hidden" name="i" value="blah" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#myform").submit();
</script>
```

Does that solve your problem?

**Edit**

If your value comes from JS, you can add it like this:

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myform input[name="i"]').val(i);
  $("#myform").submit();
</script>
```

According to your example, "i" is defined on the window scope, making it global and accessible from this script.

Comment: What if the value Im sending doesn't come from a form? It's created in Javascript? <script> $(function(){ var i = 'foo' }); </script> How do I send foo to the other page then redirect to it?

Comment: Edited in order to answer your question.

Comment: So I create the variable in JS, post it to my form, then make JS send the form. I bit odd but its worth a try.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is no other way to post a variable to another page at the same time as being redirected to that page (like you want) from Javascript / HTML. It's a hack, but it's the only way (as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

In your post example, $_POST['i'], would be your variable.

Comment: Sorry about that, I typed it by mistake. My question boils down to, how do I send a variable created in JS to another page then redirect to that page.